# Filtering cells by full match

Tags: excel, vba

Please tell me how can I make cells with the same content in `Column A` and `Column B` follow each other?

***See below screenshot:***

[image]

That is, the cell with index 6 should go immediately after the cell with index 2. and, accordingly, all other rows should be filtered in the same way. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you want to use the sort dialog box to sort under conditions.
However if you want the solution to be automatic it would be a little more complicated.
Easy solution has image below. Select DATA tab->Sort & Filter-> Select the sort box -> Sort under conditions.

If you did want the automatic Solution you may consider recording a macro because your other option would be array formulas which are complex and can slow down work book. There are new functions however that have replaced complex array and might make this easier but dont exist in all versions of excel. Do let me know if you have further questions.

[image: Sort dialog box]